# JMeter Beanshell share class definitions

Tags: java, scripting, jmeter, beanshell

is there a way to share class definitions between scripts created purely in jmeter?  For instance if I had the following structure:

```
Thread1
     -BSSampler
     -BSSample2
```

How can I create a class in BSSampler and use that same class definition in BSSample2 explicitly?  Or would I have to push the class definition out to a file and use

```
${__beanShell(source("filename.bsh"))}
```

to share the same class definitions?  Right now it's saying it doesn't recognize the class definition because it's a different namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your classes and functions in a bsh file that you reference in user.properties through:

> beanshell.server.file=../extras/startup.bsh

You can have a look at this file in extras/startup.bsh

Comment: is there a way within the jmeter app itself to set an additional search location?

Comment: for what ? jars or something else ?

Comment: jars.  like instead of adding it to the ext being able within jmeter to say "look at this location for additional jars to import".

Comment: would you mind creating a new question so that it can easily be googled by others, I 'll be happy to answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227437/jmeter-using-jar-files-outside-of-ext-folder

Comment: I answered to your question